# 2D array allocation function with one malloc in C

Tags: arrays, function, return, malloc, 2d

I need to define function for allocation 2D array, but it should call malloc only once.

I know how to allocate it (-std=c99):

```
int (*p)[cols] = malloc (sizeof(*p) * rows);
```

But i can't figure out how to return it from function. Return isn't option, because the array will stop existing once the function ends (or at least part of it). So, only options to  pass array to this function is as parametr, but the solution above needs to have defined number of cols at the declaration. Is it even possible?

Thanks.

Thanks to user kotlomoy i managed to solve this issue like this:

```
...
#define COLS 10
#define ROWS 5

int (*Alloc2D())[COLS]
{
    int (*p)[COLS] = malloc(sizeof(*p) * ROWS);
    return p;
}

//and this is example how to use it, its not elegant,
//but i was just learning what is possible with C

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int (*p)[COLS] = Alloc2D();
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            p[i][j] = j;

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            printf("%d", p[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You really should add `c99` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int * Alloc2D(int rows, int cols)
{
    return malloc(sizeof(int) * rows * cols);
}
```

Usage.

To allocate:

```
int * array = Alloc2D( rows, cols );
```

To get element [i,j]:

```
array[ cols * i + j ]
```

And don't forget to clean memory:

```
free( array );
```

Comment: Technically, there's no 2D arrays in C... even `int array[3][4]` is not 2D array. It is 1D array of 1D arrays. But you can't dynamically work with such array. Only solution with one `malloc` I gave you. Another solution would be to allocate array of pointers to rows and then allocate each row in loop.

Comment: by 2d a mean array which can be indexed with [][], which my first line of code is capable... 1D array of 1D array - yes, but in the end its acts like 2D array

Comment: Your first line is not compilable even. It is not capable to do anything. If you want to use [][] then you have to allocate array of pointers to rows and then allocate each row in loop. Also se my edit.

Comment: you need to use -std=c99 compiler option

Comment: Well, Microsoft compiler doesn't have such option. I didn't work with C99, but if your allocation works then probably you can return `int (*p)[cols]` pointer this way: `int (* Alloc2D(int rows, int cols))[cols]`

Comment: yes thats it. only [cols] has to be constant or probably global variable because [cols] at the end of function header definition seems to give undeclared error. Thanks